# How can I concatenate two JSON files to produce a single JSON result?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am getting two results, one which is in form of json and the other just as text from different sources. I need to append the results together, I have tried some methods but seems I am not getting it right.

**Here is my first code and the json result attached below**

```
const posts = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json.slice(0, 2)))
```

**Here is the json result**

```
[
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 1,
    title: 'sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit',
    body: 'quia et suscipit\n' +
      'suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\n' +
      'reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\n' +
      'nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto'
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 2,
    title: 'qui est esse',
    body: 'est rerum tempore vitae\n' +
      'sequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\n' +
      'fugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\n' +
      'qui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla'
  }
]
```

**Here is the second code and the json result attached below**

```
function generateNames(){
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    const playersName = fetch('https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players?per_page=5')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json['data'][i]['first_name']))
  }
} 
generateNames()
```

**Here is the result**

```
Ike
Ron
```

**What I am trying to achieve is something of this format**

```
[
  {
    first_name: 'Ike',
    userId: 1,
    id: 1,
    title: 'sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit',
    body: 'quia et suscipit\n' +
      'suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\n' +
      'reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\n' +
      'nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto'
  },
  {
    first_name: 'Ron',
    id: 2,
    title: 'qui est esse',
    body: 'est rerum tempore vitae\n' +
      'sequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\n' +
      'fugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\n' +
      'qui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla'
  }
]
```

Comment: just iterate over and add the field and value

Comment: I tried that using .map() function but I was getting an empty string.

Comment: Just google it, it's very common, are you merging too?

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out already. you can check the answer section as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to ensure that the data are combined once both sets of data have been fetched. Drawing on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55991302/how-do-i-combine-two-fetch-request-into-the-same-array/55991456) you can do that like this:

```
const fetchJson = url => fetch(url).then(r => r.json());
const [allPosts, allNames] = await Promise.all([fetchJson("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"), fetchJson("https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players?per_page=5")]);
const combined = allPosts.slice(0, 2).map((post, index) => ({firstName: allNames.data[index].first_name, ...post}))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function AddNames(json1) {
  var json2 = ["Ike", "Ron"];
  var i = 0;
  json1.forEach((element) => {
    element.first_name = json2[i];
    if ((i == 1)) return;
    i++;
  });
}

var posts = fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((json) => {
    AddNames(json.slice(0, 2));
  });
```

or you can use this syntax

```
async function getPosts(num) {
  let posts = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    return json.slice(0,num);
   })
  return posts;
}

async function AddNames() {
  var json1= await getPosts(2);
  var json2 = ["Ike", "Ron"];
  var i = 0;
   json1.forEach((element) => {
     element.first_name = json2[i];
     if ((i == 1)) return;
     i++;
   });
   console.log(json1);
}

AddNames();
```

Comment: I get the error TypeError: json1.forEach is not a function

Comment: const json1 = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  .then(response => response.json().slice(0, 2))

Comment: @oyerohabib json1 is the first json you posted, I don't know how you obtained it.

Comment: got it. Thank you.

Comment: Kindly help me check the continuity of the question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71057067/running-map-function-on-a-result-directly-from-an-api-gives-error

Comment: @oyerohabib I checked. What is the problem? Code in  my answer is working properly

Comment: yes it works when I use the json directly in the code but when I use the function getPosts().forEach(...), I get error, "TypeError: getPosts(...).forEach is not a function"

Comment: @oyerohabib I don't use any functions in my answer. It must be your code.

Comment: yes, the json result was a result from calling a function. instead of using the json data directly and mapping through which works pretty well, I tried using the function but that didn't work due to it returning a promise.

Comment: You could check the link to the question to understand what I meant better.

Comment: @oyerohabib I updated my answer. Pls check, I hope it will help you.

Comment: could you please explain the use of this line of code, if ((i = 1)) return;

Comment: @oyerohabib It means that we have only 2 names (0,1).