# running map function on a result directly from an API gives error

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am getting a weird kind of issue. I have a function getPosts which return a json object, when I run a .map() function on it, I get error `TypeError: getPosts(...).forEach is not a function`, but when I store the value of getPosts in a variable, such as json1 and then run the .map()
function on it, it works perfectly. I don't know why that is happening.

```
async function getPosts() {
  let posts = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    return json.slice(0, 5)
  })
}

var json2=["Ike","Ron"];
var i=0;
getPosts().forEach(element => {
  element.first_name=json2[i]; i++;
});

console.log(getPosts())
```

**Error Log**

`TypeError: getPosts(...).forEach is not a function`

**result of getPosts stored in var json1 is**

```
let json1 = [
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 1,
    title: 'sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit',
    body: 'quia et suscipit\n' +
      'suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\n' +
      'reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\n' +
      'nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto'
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 2,
    title: 'qui est esse',
    body: 'est rerum tempore vitae\n' +
      'sequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\n' +
      'fugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\n' +
      'qui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla'
  }
]
```

when I run the .map() function here, it works fine and I get the expected result

```
var json2=["Ike","Ron"];
var i=0;
json1.forEach(element => {
  element.first_name=json2[i]; i++;
});

console.log(json1)
```

**expected result is as below and works fine**

```
[
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 1,
    title: 'sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit',
    body: 'quia et suscipit\n' +
      'suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\n' +
      'reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\n' +
      'nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto',
    first_name: 'Ike'
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 2,
    title: 'qui est esse',
    body: 'est rerum tempore vitae\n' +
      'sequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\n' +
      'fugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\n' +
      'qui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla',
    first_name: 'Ron'
  }
]
```

**updated code after returning the posts**

```
async function getPosts() {
  let posts = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => json.slice(0, 5))
  return posts
}

getPosts()
```

Comment: `getPosts()` is a Promise; Promises don’t have a `forEach` method. The Promise is also useless as `posts` is never used, so the result is thrown away. You need `async function getPosts(){ return fetch(`…`).then(`…`).then(`…`); }`, then await `getPosts()` either by using top-level `await` in a module, or by wrapping `(await getPosts()).forEach(`…`);` in another `async` function.

Comment: How can i resolve that.

Comment: @KillianHuyghe, getPosts() returns this: json.slice(0, 5)

Comment: @oyerohabib No, it's your last `.then(...)` that returns `json.slice(0, 5)`. The return  value of your last  then is stored into `posts` when the Promise returns. Then you never return posts. Just  add `return posts;` at the end of `getPosts()`, that will move you forward.

Comment: I get this, "Promise { <pending> }"

Comment: I updated the question and you can see the update at the end of the question.

Comment: @oyerohabib You have a bug in your code. Check my previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71053394/11392290  I included this question too.